# In MongoDB, order documents based on a value and get the value at n'th position

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I had trouble in formulating the title of my question, so my premise there might be crooked, but here's the idea.

I have a Mongoose schema that looks something like this, I'm interested in the `rating`:

```
var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    playerName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: dataFormatValidator.playerNameValidator,
        index: {
            unique: true,
            collation: {
                locale: 'en',
                strength: 2,
                caseLevel: false // 'AbC' == 'abc'
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        validate: dataFormatValidator.emailValidator,
        index: {
            unique: true,
            sparse: true,
            collation: {
                locale: 'en',
                strength: 1,
                caseLevel: false
            }
        }
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1200
    }
});
```

I would like to tell players their positions within the whole player base, based on their rating, for instance "You are in top 31%". To avoid excessive database queries, I'm thinking about going through the players in the database once a day and saving the current ratings at each percentile in an array that would look something like this, then it would be super fast to approximate the players position:

```
[1810, 1800, 1790 ... 420, 410]
```

- Is this a good approach?
- How to index the database and query these numbers efficiently?

Comment: How would it not be more "super fast" to record the "players position" on the "player" itself? Last I checked, any type of "lookup" operation added complexity as opposed to simply directly reading data.

Comment: If the player wins matches, I want to be able to show her the progress she's making. If I'm not clever, that would require updating the position after every game, which requires going through the whole database. Doing that after every match is less super fast.

Comment: If you look at anything that runs at scale ( [what comes to mind I wonder](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01/) ), then such "leaderboards" do not update in "real time", and are only ever periodically driven. If you can store things in an "array" then it's not huge data, and if it's not huge data then you can update the user as opposed to reordering an array and looking up the index. It's just a basic logical conclusion that the argument cancels out.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other here. My plan was to just save the rating that is needed to reach each percentile in the array, that would be 99 numbers in the array. That would be used to approximate the player's ranking in "real time". The array of 99 numbers would be updated once in a while by going through the whole set of players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by defining "key points" for the ranking every 20 points and saving how many players are above each of these points. I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    { rating: 2000, playersAbove: 10 },
    { rating: 1980, playersAbove: 21 },
    ...
    { rating: 100, playersAbove: 128336 }
]
```

Then, every time a player goes across one of the limits, I will only have to update one value in the array. For instance, if a player goes from rating 1990 to 2001, I increase the 'playersAbove' of the first object in the array by one.

To get the relative ranking of a player, I check how many players are better than the "key points" above and below the player and assume that the curve is linear between them. Then I can pretty accurately approximate how many % of the players are better than him.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to:

1. Update the player `rating` after some event is finished.
2. Describe the current player's rating with respect to all players in terms of a percentage point.

And your plan to achieve this is to:

1. Record the `rating` after each "game".
2. Nightly, process all player's `rating`, creating an array which could be used as a lookup table to display a player's relative position to each other.

To me the plan sounds plausible. That is assuming that you don't need to display the percentage ratings in real time, and your nightly task can handle the number of players you have to go through. It might be challenging if you have millions and millions of players.

One possible improvement that (maybe) you can make is to create a "pre-aggregated report" by storing the array in a separate document/collection, and update this "report" (i.e. array) at the same time as you're updating the player's `rating`. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/ for more details regarding this technique.

A couple of advantages of using a pre-aggregated report is that you don't need to run a nightly task (hence it might be more scalable in the long term), and that the player's percentage number can be shown in real-time (since you're updating the array every time there's an update in any `rating`). A disadvantage of this technique is that you need to perform two updates instead of one for every `rating` update.

**Note**: the pre-aggregated report use case linked above contains details for the MMAPv1 storage engine, and sections such as pre-allocating isn't relevant anymore for the WiredTiger storage engine. However, the basic idea can be applied to either storage engine.

Comment: You understood correctly, though I'm not sure what to put in the pre-aggregated report. I think my use-case is different from the one descibed on the page you linked, because what I need for one player (the relative position) depends on all the other players.

Comment: @Antti_M the pre-aggregated report method is basically creating a document that contains the "aggregation" of newly inserted documents. Similar to calculating an average by weighting a new data point and adding it to the existing average, instead of recalculating the average value for all points every time there's a new data point. How you can implement this functionality is entirely up to you, but I believe your use case is not too dissimilar to the link I posted.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to come up with my own modified solution using the pre-aggregated method. I'll post it in case someone finds it helpful. Thank you!